# Integrating xcode4 with github, ssh, getting error when pulling / push

Tags: xcode, xcode4, github

Everything seems to be set up fine, but when I try to pull from github, I get the error
'git/master/ is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please choose a different remote branch.

when i try to push.. it tells me that the working copy is out of date and I should pull first.
What to do ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the github's quick mac setup and that seems to work fine but I didn't find any solution to what the xcode issue is !

Comment: EDIT: i was clearly unfamiliar with the proper ways of using git here but the problem was obviously basic.. you need to pull any changes before you push your commit.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem. I guess you are trying to push this project code to Github for the first time. In that case, I recommend you use Github client rather than through xcode. Xcode still seems to have incompatibility with Git in some way......